# Openlayers zoomToExtent

Tags: openlayers

I am using openlayers to draw some boundaries based on a list of lon and lat using the following code

```
        var style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
            label:areaName, 
            fontColor: "black",
            fontSize: "15px",
            fontFamily: "Arial",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            labelOutlineColor: randomColor(),
            labelOutlineWidth: 1,
            labelAlign:"lt",
            xOffset:-20,
            yOffset:-20,
            fillColor: randomColor(),
            strokeColor : randomColor()
        },OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['select']);

        var polygonFeature = new EMS.Feature.Vector(response.geometry, {}, style);

        vectorLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
```

All is working great and i get back the `boundingBox` which is an object that when i call into zoomToExtent and pass it zooms to the area around that region.

My problem is: If i have more than 2 boundingBoxes how do i calculate the region to zoomToExtent to.

Hope i am clear enough

Answer (score 3):

And i found it

```
map.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
```